# viewing a data.table by typing its name gives an error while we can view using str and glimpse

Tags: r, data.table

This has stumped me as the stupidest error in recent times.
I am working on a data.table named `log08t` and when I view it by typing its name on command line it gives this error:

```
log08t

  Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :    length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent In addition: Warning message: In cbind(time =
 c("2017-11-08 12:38:09", "2017-11-08 12:38:09",  :   number of rows of
 result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

And when I view its structure by `str` it looks like this.

```
str(log08t)

 Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 5389 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ time        : POSIXct, format: "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" ...
 $ type        : chr  "API-XML" "API-XML" "MySQL" "MySQL" ...
 $ id          : num  40192 40193 4131 4131 4131 ...
 $ gap         :Class 'difftime'  atomic [1:5389] 2.59e+01 0.00 2.71e-01 2.12e-02 3.05e-04 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ bunch2      : num  24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
 $ service_name: chr  "GetMyTodaysSessions" "GetMyCurrentSession" "SELECT" "SELECT" ...
 $ table       : chr  NA NA NA "class_sessions" ...
 $ user_id     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ code        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ from        : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ to          : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ input_string: chr  "Service : GetMyTodaysSessions; UserId : 499" "Service : GetMyCurrentSession; UserId : 499" NA NA ...
 $ contents    : chr  "5299; 2017-11-08 07:57:41; 2017-11-08 08:27:41; 6; Sanjay; 499; 17; 6th grade Physics section A; 12; Room 12A; "| __truncated__ NA "select current_timestamp" "select term.class_session_id from class_sessions as term inn..." ...
 $ break_cat   : chr  "block13" "block13" "block14" "block14" ...
 $ break_serv  : chr  "batch1" "batch2" "batch1" "batch1" ...
 $ shftime     : POSIXct, format: "2017-11-08 12:37:43" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" ...
 $ bunch       : int  23 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
 $ datetext    : chr  "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" "2017-11-08 12:38:09" ...
 $ timesec     :Formal class 'Period' [package "lubridate"] with 6 slots
  .. ..@ .Data : num  1.51e+09 1.51e+09 1.51e+09 1.51e+09 1.51e+09 ...
  .. ..@ year  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ month : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ day   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ hour  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
  .. ..@ minute: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "sorted")= chr "time"
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> enter code here
```

I can see its dimensions:

```
dim(log08t)
# [1] 5389   19
```

And I can count its rows, and see column names.

```
> nrow(log08t)
# [1] 5389
> NROW(log08t$time)
# [1] 5389
> NROW(log08t$timesec)
# [1] 5389
> names(log08t)
# [1] "time"         "type"         "id"           "gap"          "bunch2"       "service_name" "table"        "user_id"      "code"         "from"         "to"           "input_string"
# [13] "contents"     "break_cat"    "break_serv"   "shftime"      "bunch"        "datetext"     "timesec"
```

Any attempt to view it in its entirety or a subset (all columns, few rows) throws an error

But a subset of columns work,

```
log08t[,.(type,time)][1:10]

type                time
 1: API-XML 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 2: API-XML 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 3:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 4:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 5:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 6:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 7:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 8:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
 9:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
10:   MySQL 2017-11-08 12:38:09
```

The culprit, I am sure, is the last column `timesec` : After I added this column the error started.  See here,

```
log08t[,.(type,time,timesec)]
# Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
#  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
# In addition: Warning message:
# In cbind(type = c("API-XML", "API-XML", "MySQL", "MySQL", "MySQL",  :
#  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

And when I remove the column it is all normal,

```
> log08t[,timesec:=NULL]

> log08t
                     time    type    id               gap bunch2        service_name             table user_id code from to                                input_string
   1: 2017-11-08 12:38:09 API-XML 40192 2.586546e+01 secs     24 GetMyTodaysSessions                NA      NA   NA   NA NA Service : GetMyTodaysSessions; UserId : 499
   2: 2017-11-08 12:38:09 API-XML 40193 0.000000e+00 secs     24 GetMyCurrentSession                NA      NA   NA   NA NA Service : GetMyCurrentSession; UserId : 499
   3: 2017-11-08 12:38:09   MySQL  4131 2.713320e-01 secs     24              SELECT                NA      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
   4: 2017-11-08 12:38:09   MySQL  4131 2.119088e-02 secs     24              SELECT    class_sessions      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
   5: 2017-11-08 12:38:09   MySQL  4131 3.051758e-04 secs     24              SELECT student_class_map      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
  ---                                                                                                                                                                  
5385: 2017-11-08 13:14:25   MySQL  4355 1.583099e-03 secs    129              SELECT          tbl_auth      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
5386: 2017-11-08 13:14:25   MySQL  4355 3.561974e-04 secs    129              SELECT           schools      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
5387: 2017-11-08 13:14:25   MySQL  4355 4.777908e-04 secs    129              SELECT             seats      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
5388: 2017-11-08 13:14:25   MySQL  4355 3.828907e-02 secs    129              SELECT student_class_map      NA   NA   NA NA                                          NA
5389: 2017-11-08 13:14:25   MySQL  4355 4.160404e-04 secs    129              SELECT                NA      NA   NA   NA NA        

                              NA
```

I would like to know what is wrong with the last column and even if something is wrong why does data.table not replace the value by NA or NULL and move on?

Comment: Obviously, data.table does not support lubridate's period class ...

Comment: yeah seems so, as I tested by converting to a tibble and it works there.

Comment: Could the creators of `data.table` be marked on this to kindly inform all on why `lubridate` classes are not supported and when will they be supported?

Comment: Yes, of course. Go to the data.table bug tracker and submit this issue.

Comment: @Roland : turns out it is not a `lubridate` class problem. I created a small toy example and it works perfectly. So it is something to do with the `dimnames` as the error suggests. Could you relook at the error message: 
`Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`

Comment: I think I will ask another question on SO as I now have a much clearer replicable toy example. It doesn't seem to be a lubridate class thing.